# Can aurora (the geostorm) cause increased static electricity on the ground?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, charge, atmospheric-science

There was a G-1 storm last night and I had major static while taking off clothes, far more than usual. It was a clear night here not foggy like most places.

Comment: This is minor but the aurora and a geostorm are two different things. You may conclude that by the fact that a storm as opposed to the aurora doesn’t always exist.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomagnetic_storm